# Not able to add .p12 certificate in my One Signal account

Tags: ios, onesignal

I am trying to configure **One Signal push notification services** for my ios App, When I am trying to upload .p12 certificate in my account, Choose file button is not active then how i can upload my certificate. I have tried it by dragging too but not worked.

I have logged in my account, created appId then in settings I have clicked on ios platform and I reached to this step, but not able to move ahead.

Is there any set up which I missed, Can anyone please help me with this?

[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: in which site you add certificate and which certificate you submit?

Comment: on onesignal official site where i have added my app in my signed in account and i am trying to add .p12 certificate

Comment: try a different browser

Comment: already tried @Taier

Comment: can you please give me link on which you have tried?

Comment: I am also trying with the same link bt i am getting disabled choose file button

Comment: is there any thing that i am missing to set up before uploading certificates?

Comment: i am doing the same and at that time , i am getting same page as above which i have uploaded

Comment: Are you trying to upload .p12 file for Production environment ? or development environment ?

Comment: for development,actually i have tried both..But the point is "Choose file" button is not enable to select certificate and if i try to drag and drop its not working too

Comment: I get the same problem... You got It?

Comment: I finally got it using the Safari browser